# Cannot select html td link button by XPath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

My web element I'm working with:

```
<td>
<div class="linkButton" onclick="window.open('../../Report/Reports/ViewReport.aspx?reportName=Revenue.Report','Report1','scrollbars=1,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600');">Revenue Report</div>
</td>
```

This element should be clicking the link and opening a new window with

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("XPath").Click();
```

I have tried the following XPaths:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'Revenue Report')]

//*[contains(@onclick, 'Revenue.Report')]
```

Both fail with "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Are there other options for selecting this web element?

Comment: Try checking if it's in an iframe the 1st xpath should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested these in free online Xpath test site and these work:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Revenue Report')]
//div[text()= 'Revenue Report']
//td/div[text()= 'Revenue Report']
```

Also this one works from your suggestions:

```
//*[contains(@onclick, 'Revenue.Report')]
```

When I test your first suggestion, I get error:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'Revenue Report')]
```

A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("", "")